How to create an Authenticode Signing infrastructure?
I am attempting to create the necessary infrastructure to allow authorised users to sign PowerShell scripts and have them be trusted by the organisation, this allows deploying scripts to computers with the AllSigned Execution Policy.
This is the process I envision:

A Windows Certificate Authority Services server creates a RootCA (RootCA.cer).
Within that Server is a Certificate Template for a Code Signing Certificate.
The RootCA is deployed to all computers through Group Policy and placed into the Trusted Publisher Store.
A User requests a Code Signing certificate using the template (CodeSigningCert.cer), which is signed and verified by the RootCA.

At this point the Code Signing certificate (CodeSigningCert.cer) is a delegate of the RootCA (RootCA.cer), and by my assumption should qualify as a Trusted Publisher because its parent (RootCA.cer) is in the Trusted Publisher store.
However, if I sign a PowerShell script using this Certificate:
$cert = Get-ChildItem Cert:\CurrentUser\My -CodeSigningCert
Set-AuthenticodeSignature -FilePath "Z:\PowerShellTest.ps1" -Certificate $cert

And then try to run it, I receive:
Do you want to run software from this untrusted publisher?

By contrast, if I manually add CodeSigningCert.cer itself to the Trusted Publisher store then Windows happily runs the PowerShell script as it's trusted.
Please tell me:

Am I mistaken in assuming this is how AuthenticodeSignature signing chains work? (Whereby only the parent needs to be trusted and delegates can sign scripts)
If I am mistaken, what's the ideal way of signing PowerShell scripts as an organisation?
If I'm not mistaken, what am I doing wrong?


Thank you for any assistance you can provide.

You are not really mistaken, just don't know all the details. In short, code signing trust in .NET is divided in 4 levels:

Untrusted. The signature was created by an explicitly distrusted publisher. The signing certificate often are revoked when certificate holder loose his own signing private key or when it is stolen. In order to avoid lost certificate from usage (so no one will be able to use stolen certificate to impersonate legitimate user and create malicious signatures) the certificate MUST be revoked and/or placed to Untrusted Certificates container in Windows local certificate store.
Unknown publisher. The identity is not known and the signature is invalid. Because there is no verified signature, an identity cannot be determined. The signing certificate is not revoked or explicitly untrusted but is issued by untrusted Certification Authority (CA).
Known publisher. The identity is known and the signature is valid. A valid Authenticode signature provides an identity. The signing certificate is a valid certificate issued by trusted CA.
Trusted publisher. The signature is valid and was created by an explicitly trusted publisher. Signing certificates for this trust level must be issued by any trusted CA and the certificate must be placed in a Trusted Publishers local certificate store.

And PowerShell's execution policy requires Trusted Publisher trust level. This means that along with root CA certificate, you have to distribute exact code signing certificate to client's Trusted Publishers certificate container. You can do this using group policies.
p.s. I would recommend to use timestamping during signing. This will allow to run signed scripts even after code signing cert expiration. More details in my blog post: https://www.sysadmins.lv/blog-en/digital-signatures.aspx

Thanks for your help that clarifies a lot. It's a shame I couldn't deploy it the way I was envisioning but at least I know what to do now.
